# Cannot access mysql from Perl with SIP enabled on Mac Mojave

Tags: mac, mojave, apache, mysql

I'm using a Mac running Mojave as a dev server.  I got Perl talking to MySQL but if I enable SIP, anything that accesses the database chokes. Simply disabling SIP fixes it.  I have no idea what this could be or how to troubleshoot.  The error in the log is simply:

End of script output before headers: index.pl

Here is additional info from the error_log:

[Thu Sep 05 10:54:07.672203 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 3708] [client ::1:49734] AH01215: [Thu Sep  5 10:54:07 2019] index.pl: install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't load '/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle' for module DBD::mysql: dlopen(/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle, 1): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib: /Users/HTM/Sites/npbeta/index.pl

[Thu Sep 05 10:54:07.672575 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 3708] [client ::1:49734] AH01215: [Thu Sep  5 10:54:07 2019] index.pl:   Referenced from: /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle: /Users/HTM/Sites/npbeta/index.pl

[Thu Sep 05 10:54:07.672820 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 3708] [client ::1:49734] AH01215: [Thu Sep  5 10:54:07 2019] index.pl:   Reason: unsafe use of relative rpath libssl.1.0.0.dylib in /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle with restricted binary at /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 194.: /Users/HTM/Sites/npbeta/index.pl

Days of searching and nobody has an answer for this anywhere.  The only option on Mojave is to disable SIP for the file system.  Reboot and hold Command + R at the time, launch Terminal and do this:

csrutil enable --without fs

Comment: All that means is the perl file is incorrect. We would need more information.

Comment: Where is mysql located?  Maybe it needs to be moved. Enable permission for you app to access mysql.  maybe you need to enable communications between mysql and your app.

Comment: I've updated my question above with additional info in the error log.  I think it has something to do with DBD::mysql.  It runs fine if I disable SIP.

Comment: BTW mysql is located in /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql

Comment: Thanks. @historystamp see my additional comments above.

Comment: maybe you should ask over here: https://forums.mysql.com/search.php?0,search=jojave+mysql+,author=,page=1,match_type=ALL,match_dates=365,match_forum=ALL,match_threads=